# 3D plot in pandas DataSeries

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to construct a 3D plot where X and Y axis indicate the size fo the ex_one and ex_two respectively. Z represent the relations between the ex_one and ex_two manifested in 'weight' column.

I have following dataset:

```
    ex_one  fake_date         ex_two    weight
0     1          2001-07-30   695       1
1     10         2004-02-07   1405      1
2     100        2000-09-19   4832      1
3     100        2003-03-11   626       1
4     1000       2000-01-04   3993      1
5     100001     2000-01-16   213974    2
6     100001     2000-02-01   136902    1
7     100001     2000-02-08   100005    1
8     100001     2000-10-18   213963    1
9     100001     2000-12-22   100006    1
```

My goal here is to do a 3D plot

```
X = df.groupby(df['ex_one']).count() --> represents ex_one 
Y = df.groupby(df['ex_two']).count() --> represents ex_two
Z = **a series that counts df['weight'] if weight exists in ex_one and ex_two**
```

I am stuck how to do counts for Z.

If I do plot for ex_one and ex_two which is easy (2D), I get following plot.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by *"if weight exists in ex_one and ex_two"*

Comment: meaning ex_one and ex_two must exhibit relationship, thus using 'weight' column to exhibit that relations in Z axis